# Kate and indented comments

Tags: kate

Is there a way to to configure Kate so that, when I use the Comment tool, it indents the comments to where the code is currently indented? For example, consider the following Ruby code.

```
def myfunction
    puts 'hello world'
    return 'whatever'
end
```

If I invoke Comment on that first line in the function, this happens:

```
def myfunction
#   puts 'hello world'
    return 'whatever'
end
```

What I want would be this:

```
def myfunction
    # puts 'hello world'
    return 'whatever'
end
```

Furthermore, if it's invoked on several lines, I'd want them all commented evenly in the least indented column:

```
def myfunction(v)
    # if v.is_a?(Hash)
    #   @vals[k] = v
    # else
    #   @vals[k] = {'value'=>v.to_s}
    # end
end
```

Any help is appreciated.